# How to transform XML two times using XSLT?

Tags: c#, html, xml, xslt

I have to transform .xml two times with different .xslt files and I know how to transform it once, but don't have idea, how to repeat it, because when I my output was something like html string and i changed my code, by using XmlWriter instead of StringWriter (commented), but it generates an empty Xml so it can't be transferred again.

```
public static HtmlString RenderXml(this HtmlHelper helper, string xml, string transformXsltPath, string xsltPath)
    {
        xml = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(("C:/Users/Student/Documents/Visual Studio 2010/Projects/MvcApplication2/MvcApplication2/schemat.xsd"));

        XsltArgumentList args = new XsltArgumentList();
        XslCompiledTransform t = new XslCompiledTransform();
        t.Load(transformXsltPath);

        XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
        settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse;;
        using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xml), settings))
        {
            //StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
            XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(new StringWriter());
            t.Transform(reader, args, writer);
            XslCompiledTransform t2 = new XslCompiledTransform();
            t2.Load(xsltPath);
            XmlReader reader2 = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(writer.ToString()), settings);

            StringWriter writer2 = new StringWriter();
            t2.Transform(reader2, args, writer2);

            HtmlString htmlString = new HtmlString(writer2.ToString());

            return htmlString;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you are taking an XML file applying an XSLT transform the result of which (presumably a modified XML format) then has another XSLT transform applied to it?

Comment: To be honest, it is a .xsd file, which needs to be transformed with .xsl to generate HTML part of form, but then I would like to transform this again, but now with stylesheet .xsl to have generated also a CSS part of my form.